# Why does my IP address Change so frequently?

Tags: networking, routes, ip, modem

I have connected my network connection through the wireless device with DHCP. Recently I have `changed my connection from wireless to wired cable connection`. 
At that time My IP address got changed automatically,

I tried these steps [Changing Your Private IP](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-your-IP-Address-%28Windows%29)  to have my past IP address but also it changes automatically.

Now, when I check my IP address it `shows a different IP from before`. That makes 3 changes, my confusion is around whether it `changes itself` once per day or not. If anyone has an answer for this, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you talk about private IP and not Public one ?
Did you try going back to wireless for few days and watch if your private IP don't change ?

Comment: @VivenG : Ok,but i want the solution,why it gets often changes by using wired connection.

Comment: @VivenG This should be in comments and not as an answer. This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @KesaVan The best for you to have an answer is to make a diagnosis

Comment: @Rao Ok thanks but as you can see I'm new so I can't comment something that's not my answer Please can you remove your downvote, I just try to help. Thanks

Comment: @VivienG You are allowed to comment on your own question/answer but not on others' questions for a reason. For more on this pls read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51939/241953. ie., unless you earn the privilege of posting comments(which demands 50 Rep points), you should refrain from posting comments in answers and work towards getting those reputation points first. I understand and appreciate that you are trying to help, but this is how it is.

Comment: @KesaVan If you use a router check its manual to find how to use the longest lease you can (8 days is the max if I remember well). May be your lease is too short.

Comment: @VivienG: Ok Thanks frnd,But do u know the steps to check the time counter,To check that whether it is changing or not. :)

Comment: @KesaVan to be frank it's really depend on your router, check the manual it will be in DHCP section. On Windows do the following to know your lease time :
click start
click run
when the box appears type in "cmd"
then this command ipconfig /all.
it will show you when you got your least and when it expires.


if it is shorter than a day it's 99% sure it's a DHCP problem.

Answer (score 1):

Some details are missing so I can't probably make a good diagnosis of what you have here. But for now I'll try to help out.

If you are talking about your public IP address it's normal that it'll get changed quite often, unless you have signed up on your ISP for a static public IP address (ex. you told you're ISP that you'll be running a web server). It's normal for the IP to change in intervals, days, hours or even minutes if your ISP has lots of users.

If you're talking about your local IP address, you should check your router out (assuming you use one),  check if how many people are using/connected to it.

OK, so we're dealing with Private IP. Your problem is it changing whenever you Disconnect/Connect right? Are you the only user? Or are you suspecting the router might be spewing out random IPs from the IP pool even if the previous ones aren't already allocated?

Ex.

```
a) You connect, router gives you 192.168.0.2
b) You disconnect
c) Some other PC connects and gives 192.168.0.2
d) You connect again and router gives you 192.168.0.3
```

Are you talking something like the above situation?

EDIT: Silly me, found out that I can comment on my own answer.

Comment: What details ,do u want now??

Comment: I am talking about private IP,Also hooked up to router correctly,Y it gets changes automatically??

Comment: It'd be a weird incident if the lease time was so short that it'd change rapidly, because routers normally give leases that are pretty much negligible (read: long)

Edit: Check out your router settings and report some weird values you find.

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzakg%2Frzakgconceptleases.htm

A good read about leases, if they are indeed your problem.